# Using Activator.CreateInstance to create Func<T> instances

Tags: c#

Does anybody know how to dynamically create a `Func<T>` instance?

```
//Create the Func type

Type funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string)); 

//How do I pass a reference to the anonymous method? 

Activator.CreateInstance(funcType, () => "test");
```

This does not compile:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type `object[]` because it is not a delegate type

Anyone?

Comment: Try to describe what you're trying to achieve rather than how you're trying to achieve it for better chance of an answer.

Comment: I agree with Jamiec, because usually the Expression namespace is better in this kind of scenarios than hard-core reflection.

Comment: seesharper can you take a look at this light inject question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931955/lightinject-ioc-container-throws-stackoverflow-when-resolving-type

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Expression trees:

```
var func = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant("test")).Compile();
var result = func.DynamicInvoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. [This blog](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/01/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to.html) goes some way to explaining the issue.  I suggest you look for an alternative approach.  Can you use expression trees instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need a object which can be converted into `System.Object`, for this you need to create a delegate like `Func<String>` first. So it makes no sence for me to create the `Func<T>` at runtime.